# Как реализовать протокол в перечислении enum?

Tags: swift, xcode, enum

У меня есть протокол (который нельзя изменять! Даже через exctention)

```
protocol CalorieCountProtocol {
     var calories: Int { get }
     func description() -> String
}
```

Я пытаюсь реализовать перечисление enum следующим образом:

```
enum SomeEnum: CalorieCountProtocol {
    case calories(Int)
    func description() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .calories(10):
            return "wtf where elon musk its just 10 calories"
        default:
            return "yeeeeah its elon musk"
        }
    }
}

let someEnumTest: SomeEnum = SomeEnum.calories(10)
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
Type 'SomeEnum' does not conform to protocol 'CalorieCountProtocol'
```

Xcode предлагает добавить в enum *calories* в качестве переменной, но ведь я не могу сделать этого в перечеслении?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё верно в ошибке.

Ваш протокол `CalorieCountProtocol` требует наличия свойства `calories` и метода `description()`, но у вас в перечислении `SomeEnum` нет свойства `calories`.

Нельзя изменять?
Хорошо, но можно же расширить? Сделаем `CalorieCountProtocol` для перечисления, используя вычисляемое свойство и связанные значения:

```
extension SomeEnum: CalorieCountProtocol {
    var calories: Int {
        switch self {
        case .calories(let count):
            return count
        }
    }
}

print(someEnumTest.description())
print(someEnumTest.calories)
```

###### Вывод:

```
wtf where elon musk its just 10 calories
10
```

А вот в `enum SomeEnum: CalorieCountProtocol {}` необходимо убрать **CalorieCountProtocol**, иначе будет ошибка "*redundant conformance*", потому что после добавления реализации протокола `CalorieCountProtocol` в расширении для перечисления, повторное указание соответствия протоколу в определении самого перечисления становится избыточным.